# Literature on root finding of convex Functions

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis

I am interested in using a result about Newton's method, which basically states that if f is convex on $[a,b]$ and  it holds $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$, then the Newton iteration converges to $x^*\in[a,b]$ with $f(x^*)=0$ for every starting value $x_0\in[a,b]$ with $f(x_0)\geq 0$.

The proof is not that complicated. Unfortunately, I haven't found this theorem in English literature yet (only in some German [lecture notes](http://www.mia.uni-saarland.de/Teaching/MFI0708/kap52.pdf)). Could you recommend me a book or a paper, where this might be found?

Please note: I have also asked this question on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556794/literature-investigating-root-finding-of-convex-functions) (but without any success).

Comment: here's proof in English: http://www.personal.psu.edu/jjb23/web/html/sl455SP12/ch2/13Newton.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a slightly different result. It applies only to functions which are convex and have one root on $\mathbb{R}$. I can guarantee that there is only one root and convexity on an interval $[a,b]$. But I can't guarantee neither for $\mathbb{R}$ as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Global convergence of Newton's method on an interval](http://folk.uib.no/ssu029/Pdf_file/Thorlund-Petersen04.pdf), Lars Thorlund-Petersen (2004).

> Global convergence of Newton's method is considered in the strong
>   sense of convergence for any initial value in an interval. The class
>   of functions for which the method converges globally is characterized.
>   This class contains all increasing convex and increasing concave
>   functions as well as sums of such functions on the given interval.

Comment: I accepted this answer, because it is a somewhat stronger result (even though it is applied to a slightly modified Newton's Method with an iteration scheme as described by eq. (3) in the paper). It would be also interesting to have a proof, that the newton iteration is monotonically decreasing when starting at $x_0=b$ in the situation above.